# Advice re replacing all instances of text in Java string using method replaceAll

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I need to replace instances of text in a Java string and I am currently using the `replaceAll` method as follows:

```
    String originalText = ("The City of London has existed for approximately 2000 years and the City of London remains to this day.");
    String originalKeyword = ("City of London");
    String revisedKeyword = ("");
    if (String_Utils.getLengthOfKeyword(originalKeyword) > 1) {
        revisedKeyword = String_Utils.removeChar(originalKeyword, ' ');
    }
    else {
        revisedKeyword = originalKeyword;        
    }        
    String revisedText = originalText.replaceAll(originalKeyword, revisedKeyword);        
    System.out.println("Original text: " + originalText);
    System.out.println("Revised text: " + revisedText);
    System.out.println("Original keyword: " + originalKeyword);
    System.out.println("Revised keyword: " + revisedKeyword);
```

The aim of the above is to save a revised version of the original keyword without spaces, and if the number of words in the keyword is more than one, then replace all instances of the original keyword in the string.

Given that this will be a batch operation, does anyone know if there is a better way for bulk-replacing text in a Java string? Or are there any pitfalls concerning `replaceAll`?

Comment: If you're not using a regular expression, then use `replace` instead.

Comment: I will not be using `regex` fortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String originalText = ("The City of London has existed for approximately 2000 years and the City of London remains to this day.");
String originalKeyword = ("City of London");
String revisedKeyword = ("");
```

"to save a revised version of the original keyword without spaces"

```
String newVersion = new String(originalKeyword);
revisedKeyword = newVersion.replaceAll(" ","");
```

"and if the number of words in the keyword is more than one, then replace all instances of the original keyword in the string."

```
int lengthWord = originalKeyword.split(" ").length;
if(lengthWord > 0){ 
    originalText.replaceAll(originalKeyword , revisedKeyword);
}
```

Comment: This should include `originalKeyword`, not `originalText`.

Comment: It looks very much along the lines of what I have but I do need to retain the `originalText` as well.

Comment: If you need to maitain the originalText. You need to copy the originalText before replaceALl

Comment: Yes. I am doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String originalText = ("The City of London has existed for approximately 2000 years and the City of London remains to this day.");
        String originalKeyword = ("City of London");
        String revisedKeyword = ("");

        String[] arr = originalText.split(originalKeyword);
        String newString = "";

        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i += 2) {

            if(i < (arr.length -1)) {
                newString += arr[i] + revisedKeyword + arr[i+1];
            }
            else {
                newString +=  revisedKeyword + arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newString);
}
```

Here `newString` is what you are looking for.

Comment: If I use `replaceAll` to revise the original text, yes.

Comment: @MrMorgan what are you asking?

Comment: `String revisedText = originalText.replaceAll(" ", "");` looks like it will remove all spaces from the `originalText`. I don't want to do that, just to replace the instances of the `originalKeyword` with the `revisedKeyword`.

Comment: Ant to use this `revisedKeyword` to replace the instances of the `originalKeyword` in the `originalText`.

Comment: @MrMorgan check my edited code, that worked for me. And please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Mind that, internally, `replaceAll()` uses a compiled pattern to match the received string. If you wish to replace the same keyword in different original texts, you might want to cache the compiled pattern first. If it is just a one time thing, `replaceAll()` seems fine.
A faster implementation would involve implementing a replacement method from a character array containing the original text, manually identifying each substring and replacing it.
Another possible way would involve using a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), keeping track of the internal index of the last match and using [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) to substitute the keyword directly. Anything that avoids the overhead caused by `Pattern` and string's immutability.

Still, these would have to be benchmarked to identify a real need. `replaceAll()` will probably perform well enough for the case you presented.

Comment: A useful thing to know but this is a demo, not a commercial application, so I'm not too worried about performance.

Comment: Then I'd say your current method is just fine.